# Text Color Based on Background Color

Tags: html, css, colors, mix-blend-mode

I want to make a div that has text that will change color based on the background color around it. The color in the div will change between 2 different colors and I want the text color to be the opposite of those colors. So the text is black when the background is white and text is white when the background is black. I am currently using "mix-blend-mode" but I can't get the initial text color to be the opposite of the background color before the background color change. Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/CarterCo/pen/xLQWjw) of what I mean when I say the color will change. It won't be a loading bar type of change like that but you get the idea. Also here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lljat.png) from my mock-up. It is sideways because the text will be sideways on the page.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bg">
    <div class="el"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  background-color: rgb(242, 222, 183);
}

$loadingTime: 3s;
$color: rgb(165, 76, 70);

@keyframes loading {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  } 100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes percentage { 
  @for $i from 1 through 100 {
    $percentage: $i + "%";
    #{$percentage} {
      content: $percentage;
    }
  }
}

.bg {
  background-color: $color;
  animation: loading $loadingTime linear infinite;
}

.el{
  color: $color;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid $color;

  &:after {
    padding-left: 20px;
    content: "0%";
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: rgb(242, 222, 183);
    mix-blend-mode: initial;
    animation: percentage $loadingTime linear infinite;
  }
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That just makes everything fade in until 100%; I want the number to be that solid red color until the red covers in and then I want it to switch to the tan color. [Here](https://codepen.io/robinrendle/pen/wKqmbW) it is with different colors and using "mix-blend-mode: difference;"

Comment: Sure! It doesn't have to be CSS But keep in mind the color over the text will change mostly due to screen size. It will have the diagonal color split across the entire page.

Comment: I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution which lets your text be inversed depending on the background color it is an easy tutorial to follow I think.

it uses properties like `mix-blend-mode: difference;`

[Link to solution](https://css-tricks.com/reverse-text-color-mix-blend-mode/)

I hope it helps you in your coding adventure